# Spark 1.6.2's RDD caching seems do to weird things with filters in some cases

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD:

```
avroRecord: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.rr.eventdata.ViewRecord] = MapPartitionsRDD[75]
```

I then filter the RDD for a single matching value:

```
val siteFiltered = avroRecord.filter(_.getSiteId == 1200)
```

I now count how many distinct values I get for SiteId. Given the filter it should be "1". Here's two ways I do it without cache and with cache:

```
val basic = siteFiltered.map(_.getSiteId).distinct.count
val cached = siteFiltered.cache.map(_.getSiteId).distinct.count
```

The result indicates that the cached version isn't filtered at all:

```
basic: Long = 1
cached: Long = 93
```

"93" isn't even the expected value if the filter was ignored completely (that answer is "522"). It also isn't a problem with "distinct" as the values are real ones.
It seems like the cached RDD has some odd partial version of the filter.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I supposed the problem is that you have to `cache` the result of your `RDD` before doing any action on it.

Spark build a DAG that represents the execution of your program. Each node is a transformation or an action on your `RDD`. Without `cache`ing the `RDD`, each action forces Spark to execute the whole DAG from the begining (or from the last `cache` invocation).

So, your code should work if you do the following changes:

```
val siteFiltered = 
  avroRecord.filter(_.getSiteId == 1200)
            .map(_.getSiteId).cache
val basic = siteFiltered.distinct.count
// Yes, I know, in this way the second count has no sense at all
val cached = siteFiltered.distinct.count
```

Comment: @chadum, if the answer is correct, can you please mark it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code. It should work fine.

I tried out the same at my local it is working fine without any discrepancies with multiple runs.

I have following data with me:

```
Event1,11.4
Event2,82.0
Event3,53.8
Event4,31.0
Event5,22.6
Event6,43.1
Event7,11.0
Event8,22.1
Event8,22.1
Event8,22.1
Event8,22.1
Event9,3.2
Event10,13.1
Event9,3.2
Event10,13.1
Event9,3.2
Event10,13.1
Event11,3.22
Event12,13.11
```

And I tried the same thing as you did, following is my code that is working fine:

```
scala> var textrdd = sc.textFile("file:///data/pocs/blogs/eventrecords");
textrdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///data/pocs/blogs/eventrecords MapPartitionsRDD[123] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> var filteredRdd = textrdd.filter(_.split(",")(1).toDouble > 1) 
filteredRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[124] at filter at <console>:29

scala> filteredRdd.map(x => x.split(",")(1)).distinct.count
res36: Long = 12

scala> filteredRdd.cache.map(x => x.split(",")(1)).distinct.count
res37: Long = 12
```